# C# MVC EF5 deletar relacionamentos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando C# MVC e EF5 e estou com o seguinte problema:
tenho uma tela de de gerenciamento de grupo de clientes, nesse grupo eu posso inserir e remover clientes, utilizao uma tabela de relacionamento entre clientes e grupos chamada client_group_client (obviamente ela tem relação com a tabela client_group), quando eu adiciono um cliente a este grupo, eu insiro suas informações em uma table na tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código de cada uma dessas linhas é mais ou menos assim:

```
<button class="btn_remove">Remover</button> <input name="client_group_client[0].id_client" type="hidden" value="3">

<input name="client_group_client[0].id" type="hidden" value="3">

<input name="client_group_client[0].status" type="hidden" value="1">

<input name="client_group_client[0].datetime_inclusion" type="hidden" value="15/07/2014 10:06:24">

Cliente 3
```

se eu inserir um novo cliente e salvar, vai inserir um registro no banco, até ai está funcionando, o problema é quando eu tento remover um desses registros, o objeto passado para o vem apenas com as relações ativas na tela, eu não sei qual delas foi removida para poder remover do banco.
Alguém tem alguma idéia de como fazer isso?

controller ClientGroupController:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(client_group client_group, string actionSubmit, string urlReferrer)
    {
        repository.BeforeUpdate(client_group);
        if (!repository.Save())
        {
            setFlash("danger", repository.GetHtmlErrors());
            return View("~/Views/Person/ClientGroup/Edit.cshtml", client_group);
        }

        setFlash("success", I18n.T("Alert","RegisterSaveSucess"));


        if (actionSubmit == "saveAndBack")
            return Redirect(urlReferrer);
        else
            return View("~/Views/Person/ClientGroup/Edit.cshtml", client_group);
    }
```

classe Repository(criada por mim para tratar dados antes/depois de modificar):

```
public override bool BeforeUpdate(client_group obj)
    {
        foreach (client_group_client register in obj.client_group_client)
        {
            register.id_client_group = obj.id;

            if (register.datetime_inclusion == null)
            {
                register.datetime_inclusion = DateTime.Now;
                register.status = client_group_client.ACTIVE;
                dbContext.Entry(register).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                dbContext.Entry(register).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }

        return base.BeforeUpdate(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Você está enviando a `Action` de exclusão para qual `Controller`?

Comment: Cigano Morrison Mendez, editei a pergunta, veja se ajuda

Comment: Por que chamar o controller `client_group` sendo que você está excluindo uma associação `client_group_client`?

Comment: @Cigano, porquê a tela (CRUD) é referente ao client_group, dentro dela eu façoa  relação do grupo com os clientes

Comment: Não tem necessidade dessa normatização. Cada associação possui um `<form>`, certo? Depreendi isso porque você usa um botão para cada. Você pode chamar outro `controller` que faça a exclusão pra você. Fica até mais correto do ponto de vista do Design da aplicação.

Comment: @Cigano, não entendi sua colocação, está tudo dentro do mesmo <form>

Comment: Entendi. Creio que este seja o complicador. Vou sugerir uma resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o fato de você estar mandando uma instrução para o `Controller` ao qual o registro de associação pertence possa estar sendo o complicador.

A solução que eu vou passar possivelmente é bem diferente do que o que você tenha imaginado, mas é a mais simples do ponto de vista da arquitetura MVC.

Eu faria o seguinte:

### 1. Alterar o botão de Remover para um link normal

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remover", "Delete", "ClientGroupClient", new { id = client_group_client[0].id })
```

### 2. User uma Action de Delete no Controller ClientGroupClient, ao invés do Controller ClientGroup

```
// Esta Action pode abrir uma View de confirmação, mas é opcional.
// Você pode implementar apenas a Action mais abaixo.
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var clientGroupClient = dbContext.ClientGroupClients.Single(x => x.Id == id);
    return View(clientGroupClient);
}
```

Repare que para chamar esta `Action`, é preciso que seja uma requisição `POST`. Isto não é obrigatório, mas normalmente utilizo assim para garantir que haja uma confirmação para exclusão do registro, apenas por segurança.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var clientGroupClient = dbContext.ClientGroupClients.Single(x => x.Id == id);
    var clientGroupId = clientGroupClient.ClientGroupId;

    dbContext.ClientGroupClients.Remove(clientGroupClient);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "ClientGroups", new { id = clientGroupId });
}
```

Comment: realmente é uma proposta bem diferente do que eu tinha imaginado, pensei em algo que deletasse os registros ao mesmo tempo que salvasse as alterações feitas na tabela client_group, mas irei seguir seu conselho, muito obrigado

Comment: @AndrehOdon essa forma proposta pelo Cigano é bem melhor! Em minha resposta eu não quis mudar a sua forma de fazer, mas siga essa proposta msm. Mas, note q ainda assim você precisa buscar as informações no banco para saber qual cliente remover.

Comment: @Renan ficou diferente do que eu pretendia de início mas realmente funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas de resolver é:

- Obter a lista de clientes do grupo como está na sua base de dados (justamente para você saber qual foi removido);
- Alterar/Atualizar a lista de clientes conforme a remoção/edição de clientes do grupo e salvar

Exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(client_group client_group, string actionSubmit, string urlReferrer)
{        
    //Obter a lista de clientes do grupo como está na sua base de dados
    var grupo = repository.ObterGrupoPorId(client_group.IdGroup);
    //Diferença entre as listas para você alterar/atualizar a lista de clientes
    var clientesPosEdicao = ObterClientesInformadosUsuario(client_group).Except(grupo.Clientes).ToList();
    //Alterar/Atualizar a lista de clientes do grupo
    grupo.Clientes = clientesPosEdicao;
    //restante de código desejado para salvar, redirecionar, etc.
}
```

Obs.: Código não testado

Comment: Acredito que funcionaria, mas se possível preferia não ter que realizar uma nova busca no banco de dados

Comment: Renan, testei uma variação do teu código colocando isto no BeforeUpdate:
client_group group = this.Find(obj.id);

            List<client_group_client> clients = group.client_group_client.Except(obj.client_group_client).ToList();

            foreach (client_group_client register in clients)
            {
                dbContext.Entry(register).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }

porém deu o seguinte erro:
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Comment: @AndrehOdon o código de exemplo não tem relação com o método BeforeUpdate. O exemplo tenta ajudar em "qual cliente foi removido para você poder remover do banco". Esse erro é específico do EF (onde não posso te ajudar muito) e pode ser devido a algum objeto (group ou client) já está carregado no seu context. Veja https://mastigado.wordpress.com/tag/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-objectstatemanager-cannot-track-multiple-objects-with-the-same-key/ e esse link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676.